# OpenGL access shaded texture

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have a triangulated square terrain with some mountains. I use shadow mapping and pass the shadow map through my final shader. Now i want to access the shaded texture to do some post processing on the cpu, for example compare if a vertex is fully covered with shadow.

Maybe somebody can find a better one, but my first solution is to render to texture from the right camera position and save the pixels in an array.

Comment: you really want to do post processing on cpu? But yeah, render to a texture and then post process the texture.

Comment: ok it works well. i hoped there is a way to draw the scene (lots of vertices) and render to texture at once in the same shader but from different perspectives^^.